# I am unable to display the five star symbol for each member name below

Tags: php, elgg

I attached the output file in given below. Can you please check it once.[I need output like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLGiT.png)

I written the code. I am able to display the list of users name but i am unable to display the five star symbol. This is code in given below. and also attached the screenshot also. [I got output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCD71.png)

```
$users = ssp_get_items($types = 'user', $subtypes = NULL, $owner_guids = 0, $container_guids = NULL, $order_by = NULL, $offset = 0, $limit = 0, $created_time_lower = 0, $created_time_upper = 0, $count = FALSE, $callback = NULL);?>  <?php $star = '<img src='.elgg_get_config('wwwroot').'/mod/ssportal_user_verification/graphics/star.png>';      $ver = '<br>Membership Level: '. $star.$star.$star.$star.$star;  foreach($users as $user){$user = get_user($user->guid);

$vt = elgg_get_plugin_setting('ssportal_user_verification_threshold', 'ssportal_user_verification');
$uc = ssportal_member_verification_get_count($user->guid);
if($uc >= 5)
{
    $entities[] = $user;
    $ver = '<br>Membership Level: '. $star.$star.$star.$star.$star;
    }}$offset = get_input('offset', 0);$off_entities =array_slice($entities, $offset, 10, TRUE);$count = count($entities);$vars = array('items' => $off_entities,'count' => $count, // the old count parameter 'offset' => $offset,'limit' => 10,'full_view' => false,'pagination' => true,'list_type_toggle' => false,
     );$info = $vars;   echo elgg_view('page/components/list', $info);?>`
```

`

Please suggested me how to solve the above issue.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, code kind of looks like a mess.  I see two closing curly braces and only one opening brace, for example.  But what I wonder ... are you overwriting $user in your foreach loop?

Comment: Hi KKinsey, No, i am iterating the users values by using foreach loop.

Comment: That's more apparent since the code has been edited.  What are you doing with $ver?  It seems to me you simply assign it and then leave it alone.  Perhaps it should be attached to $user or to $entities somehow?

Comment: How to attached $ver to $user.Please suggested to me.